# c# ASP.NET How do i delete a file that is "in use" by another process?

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm loading a file:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FilePath);
```

Now I would like to save the image:

```
img.Save(SavePath);
```

This works.. Unless `FilePath == SavePath`, then it decides to give me the error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

So I tried to delete the file, right after opening it:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FilePath);
File.Delete(FilePath);
```

And it gives me the error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename.jpg' because it is being used by another process.
```

So...
How can I modify an existing file, that's "in use" when its not in use by anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use Memory stream or put it in byte[] array

http://www.vcskicks.com/image-to-byte.php

Answer (score 2):

The image will remain locked until it is disposed ([See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)).

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

You'll have to save the image somewhere else (or copy its contents out) and then dispose the opened image via using a `using` clause.

Example:

```
using(Image image1 = Image.FromFile("c:\\test.jpg"))
{
    image1.Save("c:\\test2.jpg");
}

System.IO.File.Delete("c:\\test.jpg");
System.IO.File.Move("c:\\test2.jpg", "c:\\test.jpg");
```

Comment: Why in heavens name would the file stay locked? its opened, read into memory, and closed? makes the Image type a PITA.

Comment: @Justin808: I'm not sure in the reasoning but the documentation says so by design, see my edit above.

Comment: This works, but the link below explains how to do this without the use of a temporary file.